# Android ArrayList compare

Tags: android, arraylist

Hi guys i got 2 ArrayList based on same class. I have to add from arraylist1 to arraylist2 non exist(s)ing rows. I tried to use contains but its always returning false. What i m doing  wrong ? Ty

MyClass

```
public class HataKoduBean {
private String Oid;
private String Name;
private String Surname;
```

}

How i define Arraylists

`Arraylist<MyClass> array1 = new Arraylist<>();
 Arraylist<MyClass> array2 = new Arraylist<>();`

How i tried to compare ?

```
 for (int ii = 0; ii < array1.size(); ii++) {
                            if (!array2.contains(array1.get(ii)))
                                array2.add(array1.get(ii));  
                        }
```

Comment: show the equals() and hashcode() implementations for the HataKoduBean class.

Answer (score 2):

First you have to implement equals() and hashCode() in your custom class.

Consider to use [Sets](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html), so you can merge collections in one line with [addAll()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#addAll(java.util.Collection)).

Answer (score 0):

First you have to implement equals() and hashCode() in your custom object
and create loop and compare between object by using equals method like this.

implement equals and hashCode:

```
`@Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o)
            return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) 
           return false;
        HataKoduBean o = (HataKoduBean) o;
        return Oid != null?Oid.equals(HataKoduBean.Oid):HataKoduBean.Oid== null;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Oid != null ? Oid.hashCode() : 0;
    }`
```

compare Objects:

`for (int ii = 0; ii < array1.size(); ii++) {
           if (!array2.get(ii).equals(array1.get(ii)))
           array2.add(array1.get(ii));
  }`